# discord bot not processing the command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was adding some new commands to my **discord v12** bot. But it's not responding to the code I typed. Any help is appreciated.
This section is inside index.js

```
client.admins = new discord.Collection();
const admins = fs.readdirSync('./custom/admin').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of admins) {
    const admin = require(`./custom/admin/${file}`);
    client.admins.set(admin.name.toLowerCase(), admin);
};
```

This is the code to process the above lines

```
if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

    const prefix = client.config.discord.prefix;

    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const admin = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const adm = client.admins.get(admin) || client.admins.find(adm => adm.aliases && adm.aliases.includes(admin));

    if (adm) adm.execute(client, message, args);
```

And the function which I am trying the bot to do is named delete.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'snap' ,
    aliases: [],
    category: 'admin',
    utilisation: '{prefix}snap [number]',

    execute(message, args) {
        if(isNaN(args)) return message.reply("Bruh,Specify how much message should I delete")
           if(args>99) return message.reply("You ain't making me do that much work boi")

           if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR') ){

            const {MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js');
            const snaping = new MessageAttachment('./snap.gif')
            message.channel.send(snaping)
         setTimeout(snapCommand , 9000 ,args, message)  

        }
      else 
      { 
        message.channel.send("-_- you are not an admin,Then why are you trying to use admin commands");
      }
      function snapCommand(args, message){
        var del= args ;
        del = parseInt(del , 10)
       message.channel.bulkDelete(del+2);
      }
    }
    
}
```

when I launch the bot it shows no error msg, So that's a good sign I think, but when I use !snap 5
'!' which is my prefix. The bot does nothing. No error in the console also. Does anyone have any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I fixed it by adding client to the delete.js code

```
execute(client, message, args) {
        if(isNaN(args)) return message.reply("Bruh,Specify how much message should I delete")
           if(args>99) return message.reply("You ain't making me do that much work boi")
```